# Facebook Application integrating Chat

Tags: facebook, xmpp

How can I integrate a php web application with facebook chat?
I have integrated the facebook application and successfully coded the granting of xmpp-login permission.  But now i need to connect using Jabber using the X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM mechanism. How can i do that? 
Facebook api reference has some explanation on these and a Python script also there.

**Facebook Explanation**:

> In order to connect using this
>   mechanism, the user must first log in
>   to your application and grant the
>   "xmpp_login" extended permission.
>   Logging in a second time to "prime"
>   the password is not required.
>
> Your application may now log in to
>   Facebook Chat via Jabber using the
>   X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM mechanism. The
>   user's Jabber ID will be assigned
>   during the resource binding step of
>   XMPP.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Jaxl library in PHP which do support X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM authentication....
http://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL